# Problem with changing in the scss file

Tags: css, spfx, style

I am facing problems that I can't change the scss file which is there when you create a SPFx webpart in React.

When I try to change color of the webpart nothing happens. I am building an RSS Feed in SPFx.

I will add a part of the code snippet in the tsx file.

**RssApp.tsx**:

```
import styles from '../RssApp.module.scss';
    let newsElement = (element: IRssItem)=> { //Newly added
        return (
              <div className = {styles.row} >
                  <div className={styles.myTitle} style={{fontSize: '30px'}}>{element.title}</div>
                  <div className={ styles.description }>{element.description}</div>

                  <div>{element.author}</div>
              </div>
        );
    };

    return (
      <div className = {styles.column}>

          <DefaultButton
            data-automation-id="test"
            text="Settings"
            onClick={this._showPanel}
          /> 
          {this.state.items.map(newsElement)}
          {settingsPanel}
      </div>


    );
```

the scss file:

**RssApp.module.scss**(As you see I have commented out the original code and added a new class (myTitle) to see if it works):

```
// @import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';



 .rssApp {
     .myTitle{
        background-color: blue;
      }
//   .container {
//     max-width: 800px;
//     margin: 0px auto;
//     box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(90, 21, 21, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
//   }

//   .row{
//     background-color: blue;
//   }

//   .row {
//     background-color: black;
//   }

//   .column {
//     @include ms-Grid-col;
//     @include ms-lg10;
//     @include ms-xl8;
//     @include ms-xlPush2;
//     @include ms-lgPush1;

//   }

//   .title {
//     @include ms-font-l;
//     @include ms-fontColor-white;
//     background-color: $ms-color-themePrimary;
//   }

//   .subTitle {
//     @include ms-font-l;
//     @include ms-fontColor-white;
//   }

//   .description {
//     @include ms-font-l;
//     @include ms-fontColor-white;
//   }

//   .button {
//     // Our button
//     text-decoration: none;
//     height: 32px;

//     // Primary Button
//     min-width: 80px;
//     background-color: $ms-color-themePrimary;
//     border-color: $ms-color-themePrimary;
//     color: $ms-color-white;

//     // Basic Button
//     outline: transparent;
//     position: relative;
//     font-family: "Segoe UI WestEuropean","Segoe UI",-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
//     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
//     font-size: $ms-font-size-m;
//     font-weight: $ms-font-weight-regular;
//     border-width: 0;
//     text-align: center;
//     cursor: pointer;
//     display: inline-block;
//     padding: 0 16px;

//     .label {
//       font-weight: $ms-font-weight-semibold;
//       font-size: $ms-font-size-m;
//       height: 32px;
//       line-height: 32px;
//       margin: 0 4px;
//       vertical-align: top;
//       display: inline-block;
//     }
//   }

 }
```

As you see, I have added a new class called myTitle and added to the styles 
**RssApp.module.scss.ts**:

```
/* tslint:disable */
require("./RssApp.module.css");
const styles = {
  rssApp: 'rssApp_9a4695d5',
  container: 'container_9a4695d5',
  row: 'row_9a4695d5',
  column: 'column_9a4695d5',
  'ms-Grid': 'ms-Grid_9a4695d5',
  myTitle: 'myTitle_9a4695d5',
  //title: 'title_9a4695d5',
  subTitle: 'subTitle_9a4695d5',
  description: 'description_9a4695d5',
  button: 'button_9a4695d5',
  label: 'label_9a4695d5',
};

export default styles;
/* tslint:enable */
```

But still no change to my RSS Feed:
[image]

Would appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks

---

Now when I make following changes: 
**RssApp.tsx**

```
    let newsElement = (element: IRssItem)=> { //Newly added
        return (
              <div className = {styles.rssApp}>
                <div className = {styles.row} >
                  <div className={styles.myTitle} style={{fontSize: '30px'}}>{element.title}</div>
                  <div className={ styles.description }>{element.description}</div>

                  <div>{element.author}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
        );
    };

    return (
      <div className={styles.rssApp}>
        <div className = {styles.column}>

          <DefaultButton
            data-automation-id="test"
            text="Settings"
            onClick={this._showPanel}
          /> 
          {this.state.items.map(newsElement)}
          {settingsPanel}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
```

And **RssApp.module.scss**:

```
@import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';

     .rssApp{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: black;

        .myTitle{
          color: red;

        }
      }
```

But instead I get the SPFx standard blue color as background color even though I haven't chosen that color in my scss:

[image]

What am I doing wrong or missing out?

Comment: I would suggest following items to double check: #1. Caching of css files. CSS files are cached by most of the browsers, please check if this is not the case. And, #2. It seems some extra characters are being appended to the style names once the web part is deployed. In this case change you css file to use selectors,like: [class^="rssApp-"],
[class*=" rssApp-"] {
  background-color: blue;
}

Answer (score 2):

As I was going through your code, I see you are missing adding top level class to wrapper container. Dont get confused here, the SCSS works in a similar way as CSS. When you nest css classes in SCSS file, it means they will follow the HTML DOM hierarchy. See the below explanation:

**SCSS File Content:**

```
.rssApp {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 10px;

     .myTitle{
        background-color: blue;
      }
}
```

This SCSS code will be transpiled to following CSS code:

```
.rssApp {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.rssApp .myTitle {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This means, in order to apply css to `myTitle` class you need to have `rssApp` class as its parent. Which is missing from the code I see you had written. So if you update line number 4 on `RssApp.tsx` file from `{styles.row}` to `{styles.rssApp}`, it will start addressing all the css changes you make for `myTitle` class.

Comment: Now in wrote my scss file like this:
`     .rssApp{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: black;

        .myTitle{
          color: red;
         
        }`

Comment: RssApp.tsx:
``` let newsElement = (element: IRssItem)=> { //Newly added
        return (
              <div className = {styles.rssApp}>
                <div className = {styles.row} >
                  <div className={styles.myTitle} style={{fontSize: '30px'}}>{element.title}</div>
                  <div className={ styles.description }>{element.description}</div>
              
                  <div>{element.author}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
        );
    };
```

Comment: but I get the SPFx standard blue background color even though I never wrote that color anywhere in my code

Comment: Hi @kelank as I read your code, it looks fine now. I guess there is some issue with `import` statement or with solution structure. I had create a github solution for you. Please read the instruction first. https://github.com/thinkb4code/scssBootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Kelank,

I think you may be experiencing issues because you need to add an element and give it the `.rssApp` class name. For example, try this:

```
import styles from '../RssApp.module.scss';
    let newsElement = (element: IRssItem)=> { //Newly added
        return (
              <div className = {styles.row} >
                  <div className={styles.myTitle} style={{fontSize: '30px'}}>{element.title}</div>
                  <div className={ styles.description }>{element.description}</div>

                  <div>{element.author}</div>
              </div>
        );
    };

    return (
<div className={styles.rssApp}>
      <div className = {styles.column}>

          <DefaultButton
            data-automation-id="test"
            text="Settings"
            onClick={this._showPanel}
          /> 
          {this.state.items.map(newsElement)}
          {settingsPanel}
      </div>
</div>
    );
```

The lines I have added are:

```
<div className={styles.rssApp}>
```

and a closing `</div>`