# Getting only blue color in SPFx even though another color in SCSS

Tags: css, spfx, react, rss

I am having trouble after with getting the desired color in my RSS webpart in SPFx. I get the standard blue from SPFx even though I have specified a background color. This question is related to the previous question I asked: [Problem with changing in the scss file](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264098/problem-with-changing-in-the-scss-file)

The code looks like this now:
 **RssApp.tsx**:

```
 let newsElement = (element: IRssItem)=> { //Newly added
        return (
              <div className = {styles.rssApp}>
                <div className = {styles.row} >
                  <div className={styles.myTitle} style={{fontSize: '30px'}}>{element.title}</div>
                  <div className={ styles.description }>{element.description}</div>

                  <div>{element.author}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
        );
    };

return (
      <div className={styles.rssApp}>
        <div className = {styles.column}>

          <DefaultButton
            data-automation-id="test"
            text="Settings"
            onClick={this._showPanel}
          /> 
          {this.state.items.map(newsElement)}
          {settingsPanel}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
```

The Scss file **RssApp.module.scss**:

```
     .rssApp{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: black;

        .myTitle{
          color: red;

        }
      }
```

Result is this:

[image]

Appreciate if someone can help me!

Comment: My guess is that it's a CSS specificity issue.  You are only using a single class selector to try to apply your style, and I'd bet that whatever is applying the blue color, the selector gives it a higher specificity value.  You can read about CSS specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: Use the browsers developer mode to find out exactly where the color settings in coming from.